# Position a MUI modal in center as per a specific (div), not by complete screen size

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, frontend

I am trying to centralize a modal inside a specific div but it automatically centralizes the modal to the complete screen center. I don't want to center it as per complete screen but as per a specific div only. I feel like I am failing to attach that specific div with my modal. Any help will be appreciated.
'**check-mate**' is the div I am targeting in which I want to place my modal.

File.js

```
<React.Fragment>
      <div
        className="check-mate"
        style={{
          backgroundColor: 'red',
          position: 'relative',
        }}
      >
        <>
          <Stack
            spacing={2}
            className="absolute right-0 mt-10 mr-10"
          >
            <Fab
              id="zoom_in"
              tooltip="Zoom In"
              size="small"
              color="primary"
              aria-label="zoom-in"
            >
              <Tooltip title="Zoom In">
                <ZoomInSharpIcon />
              </Tooltip>
            </Fab>
            <Fab
              id="collapse-all"
              size="small"
              color="primary"
              aria-label="collapse-all"
              tooltip="Collapse All"
            >
              <Tooltip title="Collapse All">
                <FuseSvgIcon>material-outline:call_merge</FuseSvgIcon>
              </Tooltip>
            </Fab>
          </Stack>
          <>
            {Object.keys(props.treeData).length > 1 ? (
              <Box
                t={2}
                ref={svgRef}
                className={"chart-container"}
                sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}
              />
            ) : (
              <FuseLoading />
            )}

            <PopupChart
              onClose={popupCloseHandler}
              show={visibility}
              data={popupData}
              title=""
              popupTabs={popupTabs}
              popupPosition={popupPosition}
              nodeName={nodeName}
              theme={theme}
            />
          </>
        </>
        {/* } */}
        {/* /> */}
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
```

Modal.js

```
import { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import popupStyles from "./Popup.module.css";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
// import amcharts_drillable_bar_chart from "./charts/popupChart";
import CircularProgress from "@mui/material/CircularProgress";
import * as am4core from "@amcharts/amcharts4/core";
import * as am4charts from "@amcharts/amcharts4/charts";

import Backdrop from "@mui/material/Backdrop";
import Modal from "@mui/material/Modal";
import Fade from "@mui/material/Fade";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";


  let margin = { top: 30, right: 50, bottom: 0, left: 100 },
    height = 320 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  const style = {
    position: "absolute",
    top: "50%",
    left: "50%",
    transform: "translate(-50%, -50%)",
    width: 600,
    bgcolor: "background.paper",

    // bgcolor: "#31333f",
    border: "2px solid #000",
    boxShadow: 24,
    borderRadius: "5%",
    p: 2,
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Modal

        aria-labelledby="transition-modal-title"
        aria-describedby="transition-modal-description"
        open={show}
        onClose={closeHandler}
        closeAfterTransition
        BackdropComponent={Backdrop}
        BackdropProps={{
          timeout: 500,
        }}
      >
        <Fade in={show}>
          <Box sx={style}>
            <Typography
              variant="h6"
              sx={{ textAlign: "center" }}
            >
              {nodeName}
            </Typography>
            {props.data.length > 0 ? (
              <Box sx={{ width: "100%" }}>
                <Tabs
                  value={tabValue}
                  onChange={(event, value) => setTabValue(value)}
                  textColor="secondary"
                  indicatorColor="secondary"
                  aria-label="secondary tabs example"
                  onClick={(e) => {
                    console.log("Came here 01");
                  }}
                >
                  {props.popupTabs.map((element, i) => (
                    <Tab
                      key={element}
                      onClick={(e) => {
                        console.log("Came here");
                        setActiveTab(element);
                      }}
                      label={element}
                      value={element}
                    />
                  ))}
                </Tabs>
                {
                  <Box
                    id="popup_chart"
                    sx={{
                      height: height + margin.top + margin.bottom + "px",
                      alignItems: "center",
                    }}
                    className={"svgWrapper"}
                  ></Box>
                }
              </Box>
            ) : (
              <Typography
                variant="p"
                gutterBottom
                component="div"
                sx={{ textAlign: "center" }}
              >
                No Drills available for this node
              </Typography>
            )}

            {loading && (
              <Box
                sx={{
                  display: "flex",
                  flexGrow: 1,
                  justifyContent: "center",
                  alignItems: "center",
                  position: "absolute",
                  top: "50%",
                  right: "50%",
                }}
              >
                <CircularProgress color="success" />
              </Box>
            )}

            {/* <Box id='popup_chart' sx={{  
                    height: height + margin.top + margin.bottom + 'px',
                    alignItems: 'center'}} >
            </Box> */}
          </Box>
        </Fade>
      </Modal>
    </div>


  );
```

[image]